# Scala: determine method result type for use in generics

Tags: scala, generics

In a third-party library there is a series of request classes, all of which derive from some common base class, which is generic and takes response class as a parameter:

```
abstract class AbstractRequest[ResponseType] {
  …
  def execute(): ResponseType
}

class UserList {…}
class UserListRequest extends AbstractRequest[UserList] {…}

class Avatar {…}
class AvatarRequest extends AbstractRequest[Avatar] {…}

…
```

I want to write some generic method that takes a request instance, executes it several times in some special ways and delegates processing of the responses to a function supplied in arguments:

```
def specialMultiExecute(request: Req)(responseHandler: Resp => Unit): Unit = …
```

— to be called like:

```
val myRequest: UserListRequest = …
specialMultiExecute(myRequest){ userList => … }
```

The problem is that I need to somehow specify `Req` and `Resp` types in the `specialMultiExecute` declaration. I tried the obvious approach:

```
def specialMultiExecute[Req <: AbstractRequest[Resp], Resp](request: Req)(responseHandler: Resp => Unit): Unit = …
```

— but Scala compiler fails to deduct generic argument types (an explicit specification like `specialMultiExecute`**`[UserListRequest, UserList]`**`(myRequest){ userList => … }` is required).

In C++ in such case I could write a template function with a single template parameter `Req`, while making `Resp` to be determined as *result type of the method `Req::execute`*:

```
template<typename Req>
void specialMultiExecute(
    Req request,
    std::function<void (decltype(std::declval<Req>().execute()))> responseHandler
) {…}
//i.e. we use `decltype(std::declval<Req>().execute())` instead of Resp
```

Is there way to write something similar is Scala?

I mean something like (in Scala-like pseudocode):

```
def specialMultiExecute[Req <: AbstractRequest](request: Req)(responseHandler: ResultTypeOf(Req#execute) => Unit): Unit = …
```

Comment: Do you need to know which sub type of `AbstractRequest` do you have, or are you fine wit only knowing which `ResponseType` you have?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, to say truth, it seems it's better for `specialMultiExecute` to know an exact subtype of `AbstractRequest`. (This may be non-obvious from the explanation above, but it's related to some unspecified dirty details on how `specialMultiExecute` internally works.) However, if I understand correctly, your first example covers this case (I'm now trying to read and understand how it works).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a limitation of the type inference mechanism.
The simplest way to solve it is to use an *implicit evidence* that `Req` is a **subtype** of `AbstractRequest[ResponseType]`.

Here is an example.

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

abstract class AbstractRequest[ResponseType] {
  def execute(): ResponseType
}

final case class User(id: Int, name: String)
final case class House(id: Int, price: Int)

class UserListRequest extends AbstractRequest[List[User]] {
  override def execute(): List[User] = List(User(id = 3, name = "Sasha"))
  override def toString: String = "UserListRequest"
}

final class RequestWrapper[Req, Resp](val request: Req) extends AnyVal {
  type ResponseType = Resp
}

implicit def request2wrapper[Req, Resp](request: Req)(implicit ev: Req <:< AbstractRequest[Resp]): RequestWrapper[Req, Resp] =
  new RequestWrapper(request)

def specialMultiExecute[Req, Resp](wrapper: RequestWrapper[Req, Resp])
                                  (responseHandler: wrapper.ResponseType => Unit)
                                  (implicit ev: Req <:< AbstractRequest[Resp], TTReq: TypeTag[Req], TTResp: TypeTag[Resp]): Unit = {
  val request: Req = wrapper.request
  val executionResult: Resp = request.execute()
  responseHandler(executionResult)
  println(TTReq)
  println(TTResp)
  println(request)
}

specialMultiExecute(new UserListRequest())(println)
// List(User(3,Sasha))
// TypeTag[UserListRequest]
// TypeTag[List[User]]
// UserListRequest
```

> [**Reference**](https://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html) for `<:<`.
>   [**Reference**](http://wheaties.github.io/Presentations/Scala-Dep-Types/dependent-types.html#/) for *"Dependent types"*.

## Edit

Te above code example was modified to allow identification of the concrete `Request` and `Response` types being used.

Comment: Although your answer doesn't answer my question directly (i.e. whether it is possible to get method result type in a way usable for generics), I got plenty other useful information from it. Therefore I accept it. (Additionally I found a way to make _dirty internal details_ of `specialMultiExecute` to work without knowing exact `Req` type.)

Comment: Hi @Sasha, I'm glad it help you. I think the first code snippet provides you with all the information you need. _(e.g. The exact type of `Req` & `Resp`)_, or am I missing something ?

Comment: In the first snippet `Req[ResponseType]` is `AbstractRequest[List[User]]`, not `UserListRequest`. We can check that, for example, by `println(scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[Req[ResponseType]])`.

Comment: @Sasha ah, you're right. The reason is that `UserListRequest` doesn't match the signature type `Req[_]` since it doesn't takes any type argument - my bad, sorry. I think I can fix it, and will update the answer once it is done.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, now the type of response still needs to be specified during a call, although it has moved from [UserListRequest, List[User]] to `l: List[User]` (but yeah, now we need to specify only `Resp`, not both `Req` and `Resp`). Anyway, as said before, I had found a way to make `specialMultiExecute` to work without knowing exact `Req` type, so now it's just for satisfying my thirst for research.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184099/discussion-between-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez-and-sasha).